# Vertex Color Paint Rendering in Blender v3

Tags: rendering, vertices, vertex-colors

I'm going totally crazy. I have my nodes all set, the Vertex colors are named something other than 'Col,' and everything is ready to go for rendering. However, every guide on the Internet tells me to "Open the properties tab and check the Vertex Color Paint box." Without it, I won't be able to see my vertex colors in the rendering.

Does this box even exist in Blender v3? I have looked EVERYWHERE for it, up and down. I got excited because there was a similarly named option under Bake. Is baking now the only way to see vertex coloring in a render? Am I missing the feature somewhere? Please help me! I just can't seem to get these colors to correctly show in the render. It's worth noting the base colors and blushing are part of the same vertex color set, in this case 'Skin.'

[image: Example of node]

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the final result. You can compare it to the preview version of the sculpt and see how, although basic colors render, a great deal of the blushing detail on the sculpt is just absent.

[image: Render result]

As requested, here are my render settings. I haven't touched anything at all, so far as I am aware.

[image: render settings]

Thank you to everyone replying! I hope we can figure this out, it's like the last thing standing between me and really feeling comfortable with Blender lol...until I find the next thing, anyway.

Comment: Have you try to render a test for your scene? I'm asking this, because by default should work, share your render settings (screenshots), the more info, the better.

Comment: Do you mean this option ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV2jg.png

Comment: Hey Emir! Yes, I have tried rendering. The base color of the vertex painting shows through, IE the flesh tone, but details like blushing and other lighter colorations of the skin are totally absent. I will add more screenshots to demonstrate. And no, Gorgious, I tried that option and it didn't change this problem.

Comment: FOUND THE ANSWER. I remembered while troubleshooting that early in this process I assigned dummy materials to certain objects to see their shapes more easily. Apparently these old materials were still assigned!!!! lol I feel very stupid, but thank you for everyone who helped me! You guys helped me narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

I remembered while troubleshooting that early in this process I assigned dummy materials to certain objects to see their shapes more easily. Apparently these old materials were still assigned.